# Guardar datos en SQLite y mostrarlos en un listView. Por qué no arranca?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-listview

Estoy intentando crear una app en la que escribes un nombre de jugador en un EDITTEXT y al pulsar un botón lo almacena en una tabla de una base de datos SQLite.

La app también contaría con un LISTVIEW que mostraría los nombres de jugador almacenados en la tabla de la base de datos.

El problema es que la app da error al arrancar y no sé el motivo. ¿Podéis ayudarme? Muchísimas gracias y disculpadme si he cometido algún error al preguntar, es la primera vez que escribo en este foro.

La app consta de un MainActivity y una clase llamada "DAOHelper"

Éste es activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirmarNuevoJugador"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnConfirmarNuevoJugador"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etJugador"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/etJugadorHint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnConfirmarNuevoJugador"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvJugadores"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="636dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etJugador"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Éste es el MainActivity.java:

```
package com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DAOHelper d;
    private EditText etJugador;
    private Button btnConfirmarNuevoJugador;
    private ListView lvJugadores;

    public MainActivity(DAOHelper d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etJugador = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etJugador);
        btnConfirmarNuevoJugador = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmarNuevoJugador);
        lvJugadores = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvJugadores);

        agregarJugador();
        listarDatos();
    }

    public void agregarJugador(){
        btnConfirmarNuevoJugador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(etJugador.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Escribe un nombre de jugador",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    String jugador = etJugador.getText().toString();
                    long res = d.agregarPersona(jugador);
                    if(res != -1){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Jugador creado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"El jugador ya existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        etJugador.requestFocus();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void listarDatos(){
        ArrayList<String> lista = d.obtenerPersonas();
        if(!lista.isEmpty()){
            lvJugadores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista);
            lvJugadores.setAdapter(adaptador);
        }else{
            lvJugadores.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

Y ésta es la clase "DAOHelper":

```
package com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DAOHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //private static String MI_BD = "BASE_DATOS";
    private static String MI_TABLA = "JUGADORES";

    public DAOHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crearTabla ="CREATE TABLE "+MI_TABLA+" (NOM_JUG TEXT PRIMARY KEY)";
        db.execSQL(crearTabla);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+MI_TABLA);

    }

    public long agregarPersona(String jugador){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("NOM_JUG", jugador);

        long res = db.insert(MI_TABLA,null,cv);
        db.close();
        return res;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> obtenerPersonas(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor datos = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+MI_TABLA+" ORDER BY NOM_JUG ASC",null);
        ArrayList <String > lista = new ArrayList <String> ();
        while(datos.moveToNext()){

            String jugador = (datos.getString(0));

            lista.add(jugador);
        }
        db.close();
        return lista;
    }
}
```

El mensaje de error que me aparece en el simulador al intentar arrancar la app es simplemtente "DB to listView2 has stopped".

Y en el logcat aparece esto:

```
2021-06-08 20:07:10.882 3185-3185/? I/l.dbtolistview: type=1400 audit(0.0:1546): avc: denied { sendto } for path="/dev/socket/logdw" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_dgram_socket permissive=1
2021-06-08 20:07:10.887 3185-3185/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-06-08 20:07:10.933 3185-3185/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-08 20:07:10.990 3185-3185/? I/JDWP: type=1400 audit(0.0:1547): avc: denied { connectto } for path=006A6477702D636F6E74726F6C scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
2021-06-08 20:07:11.194 3185-3185/? I/JDWP: type=1400 audit(0.0:1548): avc: denied { read write } for path="socket:[26910]" dev="sockfs" ino=26910 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
2021-06-08 20:07:19.032 3185-3185/com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2-2/lib/x86
2021-06-08 20:07:21.076 3185-3185/com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-08 20:07:21.104 3185-3185/com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2, PID: 3185
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2/com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2.MainActivity> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: no debes agregarle un constructor a las activities. Simplemente crea el `DAOHelper` en el método `onCreate` o usa una librería de [inyección de dependencias](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Muchas gracias por responder. Tu respuesta me ha dado la pista que necesitaba para solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta del compañero  @SinneroftheSystem me ha dado la pista que necesitaba para encontrar el problema.

Adjunto cómo ha quedado el código finalmente.

Éste es el MainActivity.java:

```
package com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DAOHelper d;
    private EditText etJugador;
    private Button btnConfirmarNuevoJugador;
    private ListView lvJugadores;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        d = new DAOHelper(this);

        etJugador = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etJugador);
        btnConfirmarNuevoJugador = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmarNuevoJugador);
        lvJugadores = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvJugadores);

        agregarJugador();
        listarDatos();
    }

    public void agregarJugador(){
        btnConfirmarNuevoJugador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(etJugador.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Escribe un nombre de jugador",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    String jugador = etJugador.getText().toString();
                    long res = d.agregarPersona(jugador);
                    if(res != -1){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Jugador creado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        listarDatos();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"El jugador ya existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        etJugador.requestFocus();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void listarDatos(){
        ArrayList<String> lista = d.obtenerPersonas();
        if(!lista.isEmpty()){
            lvJugadores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista);
            lvJugadores.setAdapter(adaptador);
        }else{
            lvJugadores.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

Y ésta es la clase "DAOHelper":

```
package com.doctoractual.dbtolistview2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DAOHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String MI_BD = "BASE_DATOS";
    private static String MI_TABLA = "JUGADORES";

    public DAOHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, MI_BD, null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crearTabla ="CREATE TABLE "+MI_TABLA+" (NOM_JUG TEXT PRIMARY KEY)";
        db.execSQL(crearTabla);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+MI_TABLA);

    }

    public long agregarPersona(String jugador){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("NOM_JUG", jugador);

        long res = db.insert(MI_TABLA,null,cv);
        db.close();
        return res;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> obtenerPersonas(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor datos = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+MI_TABLA+" ORDER BY NOM_JUG ASC",null);
        ArrayList <String > lista = new ArrayList <String> ();
        while(datos.moveToNext()){

            String jugador = (datos.getString(0));

            lista.add(jugador);
        }
        db.close();
        return lista;
    }
}
```